# Photoshop - Using artboards to automatically generate/preview multiple sizes of a particular artboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to automate previewing in a single Photoshop document, multiple sizes of a particular artboard?

For example, this is quite useful for icons, to see how a design scales from the large 1024x1024 to 512x512 to the 324x324 to the 64x64.

Ideally, the other sizes could be automatically generated from a particular artboard - say, the 1024x1024 one.

Comment: Maybe artboards are not the right way? Surprised no one has any replies or answers...